# c++ dynamic allocation for a copy of a class pointed by a pointer

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor

I have a class `class1` with its a constructor `class1(int i)` and a copy constructor `class1(const class1& other)`.

Instances of `class1` are created dynamically, since the `int` argument is not known at compile time.

My problem is that I have to pass this pointer between a producer object and a consumer object:

```
void producer::produceAndSend(...) {
    class1 *c1 = generate(...); 
    consumerObj.set(c1);
}

class consumer {
    class1 *internalC;
    void set(class1 *c);
}

void consumer::set(class1 *c) {
    this->internalC = c; //This only copies the pointer, not the content
}
```

I would like to store a copy of the object pointed by `c1` and this copy must be pointed by `internalC`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can do `internalC = new class1(*c)`.

Comment: this causes `error: cannot convert ‘class1**’ to ‘class1*’ in assignment`

Comment: Can you post the updated `consumer::set` implementation because I think 0x49... suggestion looks right.

Comment: `void consumer::set(class1 *c) {
    this->internalC = new class1*(c); 
}`

Comment: @the_candyman You've got the `*` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Instances of class1 are created dynamically, since the int argument is not known at compile time.

That's not what dynamic allocation is for. You can create an object with automatic storage duration with runtime parameters. In fact, by not using dynamic allocation, your problem is solved automatically and won't involve you leaking memory.

```
void producer::produceAndSend(...) {
    class1 c1 = generate(...); 
    consumerObj.set(c1);
}

class consumer {
    class1 internalC;
    void set(class1 c);
}

void consumer::set(class1 c) {
    this->internalC = c; //This only copies the pointer, not the content
}
```

Comment: as I said, the constructor of `class1` is `class1(int i)`. What you wrote cannot work.

Comment: @the_candyman, Yes, it can. Easily. Please read the relevant section of your book again.

Comment: @the_candyman For what reason? Because `consumer` will default construct `internalC`? Well you have some options. The first is to give `class1` a default constructor, the second is to give `consumer` a constructor which constructs `internalC` by passing it some `int`, and the third option is to use `boost::optional<class1> internalC;` if you want it to be that `internalC` doesn't exist until it's set.

Comment: I don't have a default constructor. I only have the constructor with input arguments

Comment: ["give consumer a constructor which constructs internalC by passing it some int"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: Consumer is created independently from the parameter `int i` used to construct the object. `i` is evaluated at runtime, it can change and the creation of `internalC` can be perfomed a lot of time. Anyway, I think I got your point, but I prefer a way without altering the class or using boost